# What is the pattern/property in this poem?

Tags: pattern, word-property, poetry

Here is a poem in the Persian language which has a special property.

The language itself does not affect the pattern and there is no need-to-know Persian to find the pattern.

The pattern can be applied to any similar text in any language, but the result requires it to be meaningful, which is the difficult part.

The pattern applies to words (not the characters), so it is easy to find it by considering words/group of words as a shape.

با قامت افروخته گل را مشکن

افروخته رخ مرو تو دیگر به چمن

گل را دگر خجل مکن ای مه من

مشکن به چمن ای مه من قدر سمن

Edit:
The phrase **`با قامت`** is as **`از چهره`** in some references.

Solution as described by @Bass:

> [image]

A description about the format of this poet:

> This format is called as `مربع` which means `Square` in English. It can be read both vertically and horizontally (right to left in Persian).

In other languages:

> Here is an English poet in this format as mentioned by @Chris Sunami:
>  [Form For All: On Lewis Carroll and Square Poems](https://dversepoets.com/2012/06/28/form-for-all-square-poems/)

Comment: I don't think this will be helpful, but here is what Google Translate says this is in English (ROT13): `Ur oebxr gur sybjre jvgu uvf fjbyyra fgngher. Ghea lbhe snpr gb gur tenff. Qba'g or nfunzrq bs gur sybjre, zl zvfg. Vg vf nf uneq nf gur tenff bs gur sbt.`

Comment: @DanielMathias: At first, I tried to put the poet as a table in the spoiler block, but it did not show properly. Please let me know if spoiler block accepts pictures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I can't read this at all, but since OP says that's not a requirement, let's have a go:

Each row has the same symbol on the left, so this poem probably rhymes. (Persian is read from right to left, I believe.)

That same symbol is also present at the end of words on the bottom row a lot:

> [image]

Combining that with the given hint of

> The pattern can be applied to any similar text in any language, but the result requires it to be meaningful, which is the difficult part.

I'll just go ahead and guess that maybe

> you can read this poem either horizontally or vertically

and it still rhymes.

But wait, there's more! <sub><sup>(NB: while I was editing this in, @Stevish [posted the same observation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/123416/36023))</sup></sub>

Looks like the idea above can be extended a bit:

> [image]

Apart from the missing letter(s?) in the ellipse, the poem is the exact same read in either direction.

I don't know anything about the language, so let's wait for someone who does to pass their judgement on whether the missing part is intentional or just a typo :-)

Comment: I think you've hit on it at the end! That's totally it. I missed that in my answer, though I saw the basic pattern you saw.

Comment: Both answers are correct, but this is the more accurate. The parts highlighted in magenta ellipse (`دگر` and `دیگر`) are equal in Persian and is not a typo. But I should use the same style for both of these words so it could be more readable.

Comment: This format also exists in English, as invented/discovered by Lewis Carroll: https://dversepoets.com/2012/06/28/form-for-all-square-poems/

Answer (score 6):

[EDIT: My answer here is only the first half of the complete answer. If you need a hint, my answer might point you in the right direction...]

I found *A* pattern at least:

> [image]
>
>  The top left and bottom right corners are rotations of each other. The 1st line starts with the same three words/phrases that end the 4th, 3rd and 2nd lines respectively, and the 4th line ends with 3 words/phrases that begin the 3rd, 2nd and 1st lines. It's a little visually disappointing that the last phrase in the first line isn't the same as the first phrase in the last line, but you get what you get.